# CollectionView horizontal scrolling with pagning when cells are not screen size - Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

So basically, I have a horizontal collectionView using cells with a width less than the screen's width. It looks something like this (You can see a small part of the next cell to the right, and also note that I use contentInsets on the left to center the cell):

[image]

However, the image above only shows how the first cell looks with isPagingEnabled set to true. If I were to scroll to the next cell, it would look like this instead:

[image]

Here you can see how the property isPagingEnabled is making the collectionView scroll to far, and thus not centering the cell in the screen as it was initially. So basically, what I want to accomplish is to make the paging work even though the cells' widths isn't the same as the screen's. I want the cell to be centered as it is in the first picture, regardless of indexPath considering it currently only works for the first cell. So my question is therefore, how can I make the paging work if my cells' width isn't the same as the screen's?

Furthermore, I would like to point out that I am aware that there is similar questions. However, these are mostly comprised of answers written in Objective-C, and because I only write in Swift, an answer in Swift is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for this problem

I created custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout class.

```
class PagingCollectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    
    override func targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint,
                                      withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return proposedContentOffset }
        
        let pageLength:        CGFloat
        let approxPage:        CGFloat
        let nextOrCurrentPage: CGFloat
        let speed:             CGFloat
        
        
        if scrollDirection == .horizontal {
            
            pageLength = (self.itemSize.width + self.minimumLineSpacing)
            approxPage = collectionView.contentOffset.x / pageLength
            speed      = velocity.x
            
        } else {
            
            pageLength = (self.itemSize.height + self.minimumLineSpacing)
            approxPage = collectionView.contentOffset.y / pageLength
            speed      = velocity.y
            
        }
        
        
        
        if speed < 0 {
            
            nextOrCurrentPage = ceil(approxPage)
            
        } else if speed > 0 {
            
            nextOrCurrentPage = floor(approxPage)
            
        } else {
            
            nextOrCurrentPage = round(approxPage)
            
        }
        
        
        
        guard speed != 0 else {

            if scrollDirection == .horizontal {
                
                return CGPoint(x: nextOrCurrentPage * pageLength, y: 0)
                
            } else {
                
                return CGPoint(x: 0, y: nextOrCurrentPage * pageLength)
                
            }
            
        }
        
        
        
        let nextPage: CGFloat = nextOrCurrentPage + (speed > 0 ? 1 : -1)
        
        
        if scrollDirection == .horizontal {
            
            return CGPoint(x: nextPage * pageLength, y: 0)
            
        } else {
            
            return CGPoint(x: 0, y: nextPage * pageLength)
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

When init your collectionView set PagingCollectionViewLayout as collectionViewLayout.

For example:

```
let layout = PagingCollectionViewLayout()
let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
```

Result:

[image: example]

You can also find more details here: https://github.com/Hank2354/PagingCollectionViewLayout

Comment: Thanks for the 3 examples in your github project!